# FLV to MP4 conversion keeping PTS consistent

Tags: ffmpeg

The input file has the following video settings but playsback in media player at 29.97 FPS

```
Video
Format                      : AVC
Format/Info                 : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile              : Baseline@L2.1
Format settings             : 2 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC      : No
Format settings, ReFrames   : 2 frames
Codec ID                    : 7
Duration                    : 1 min 30 s
Width                       : 480 pixels
Height                      : 360 pixels
Display aspect ratio        : 4:3
Frame rate mode             : Constant
Frame rate                  : 14.985 (15000/1001) FPS
Color space                 : YUV
Chroma subsampling          : 4:2:0
Bit depth                   : 8 bits
Scan type                   : Progressive
Color range                 : Limited
Color primaries             : BT.601 NTSC
Transfer characteristics    : BT.709
Matrix coefficients         : BT.601
```

However, another coded application will not accept the file as a valid file frame rates are only NTSC or PAL
How can I force the frame rate to be presented as 29.97 without changing the duration of the clip?

Comment: You would have to transcode to modify the frame rate.

Comment: Which coded application? Can you share the input?